# Why does my Powershell IF...Else loop always do the ELSE statement, no matter what the variable result is?

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I am making a simple script for my internship in powershell, that uses simple stuff like variables, the IF...ELSE statement, as well as Get-Counter.

```
$CpuLoad = "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time"
$Threshold = 50
Get-Counter -Counter $CpuLoad -SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples 10
IF($CpuLoad -gt $Threshold) {
Write-Host "CPU Utilizacija ir lielaka par 50 procentiem!"
} Else {
Write-Host "Viss ok!"
}
```

That is the script. No matter what the CPU utilization percentage is, it will always say the **ELSE** write-host statement, **not the IF** write-host statement. Do not worry. I am not trying to cheat or anything of the sort ;). I'm simply dumb-founded as to how such a simple script can break so easily! Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You're comparing the string value `"\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time"` with the integer `50`, an operation that will always return `$false` (alphabetically speaking, ``\`` precedes `5`). Did you mean to inspect the output from `Get-Counter` to test if any sample values exceed the threshold instead?

Comment: Yes, I want. The purpose of the script is to read the output from the Get-Counter, and then later check and see, if it is greater than $Threshold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing the string `"\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time"` to the number `50` doesn't make much sense.

Instead, use `Where-Object` to test if any of the counter samples returned by `Get-Counter` exceeds the threshold:

```
$CpuLoad = "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time"
$Threshold = 50
$samplesExceedingThreshold = Get-Counter -Counter $CpuLoad -SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples 10 |ForEach-Object CounterSamples |Where-Object CookedValue -gt $threshold |Select-Object -First 1

if($samplesExcheedingThreshold){
    Write-Host "CPU Utilizacija ir lielaka par 50 procentiem!"
} else {
    Write-Host "Viss ok!"
}
```

Comment: It is interesting. Thank you for the tip! However, after testing your solution, it seems that giving the 'Processor Time' command a variable makes it a string no matter what I do. Is it not possible to use Get-Counter with a variable that is supposed to contain a difference command?

Comment: @PaulsEglītis I'm afraid I don't understand your question.

Comment: So, the line with Get-Counter is supposed to get sampled of the CPU usage, or so to speak... When I call the variable used to define the Get-Counter (it being $samplesExceedingThreshold), it calls the string "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time", instead of the actual values that Get-Counter is supposed to provide. Is it not possible to get the actual measurements of the counter?

Comment: I just realized that Mathias made an error in the script. The second time he referenced the $samplesExceedingThreshold, he made a Typo, which, of course, broke the entire script. Thank you for your help. <3